# How to reset the client and rest keys for parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using parse.com is there a way to reset the client and rest keys?

I reset the master key, but that didn't seem to do it. (I verified that the Master key changed).

I could delete the app since it isn't yet in production, but was hoping there was a less draconian alternative

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to e-mail parse.com support and ask them to do it. There is no option on the web interface to do it. Generally changing these keys breaks clients so it isn't something you do regularly (if ever).

Comment: Good to know. I think at this stage of development it's just as easy for me to delete the application and spinup another one.